# how to avoid for loop using apply function in this question

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, apply

```
mat<-matrix(1:9,nrow=3,ncol=3)
for(i in 1:3){
  print(colSums(mat[1:i,]))
}
```

I'm trying to calculate mean of colSums of part of a matrix. 
[image]
How do I avoid for loop in this case? The answer may be similar to the code below but I don't know how to proceed.

```
apply(mat,2,function(x) colSums(mat[]))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) `mat<-matrix[1:9,nrow=3,ncol=3]` isn't valid R code. 2) Your `for` loop gives an error while running. 3) What do you mean by `calculate mean of colSums of part of a matrix.` 4) What is your expected output ?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me! I add a screenshot. I want to print colSums of a part of a  matrix, like mat[1:i,] in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `cumsum()` to get the sums and `rowMeans()` to get the means:

```
apply(mat, 2, cumsum)[2:4, ]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    3   11   19   27
# [2,]    6   18   30   42
# [3,]   10   26   42   58
rowMeans(apply(mat, 2, cumsum)[2:4, ])
# [1] 15 24 34
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there an encyclopedia where I can learn all these basic stuff? I find online introduction like tutorialpoints far from enough.

Comment: I have a collection of web links for learning R at [Web Resources for R](https://sites.google.com/a/tamu.edu/dlcarlson/home/r-project-for-statistical-computing/r-resources-on-the-web). I've also found the books _R For Dummies, 2nd Edition 2nd Edition_ by Andrie de Vries and Joris Meys and _R in Action: Data Analysis and Graphics with R_ by Robert Kabacoff to be helpful introductions.